# Recommend books on Lat Long

Tags: mathematics, geometry

I am a lyaman of Geography, and working on a project to calcuate
x,y (from a rectangle coordinate system) to Lat,Long
I searched on the net, and fell complete lost in the big world of geometry, geography, and mathe.
Could someone please recommend books/pdf on learning these stuffs from a newbie?
Thanks!

Comment: They even have their own stackexchange website, https://gis.stackexchange.com ! Conversion between coordinates is not always very straightforward and can involve some hard mathematics; you can try here https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=3857 for one example of (lon,lat)->(x,y) conversions, but there are many (lon,lat) and (x,y) reference systems. As a bonus, if it's just to find how an image relates to a map, try georeferencing, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKLBFddpTGI . (plus, your question is a bit open-ended, hard to see what a right answer on this site should be!).

Comment: @Erik Thanks for you help !  I will check those useful links ! BWT, I borrow a book name "Basic GIS Coordinates" from others, hope I can learn some new stuff.

Answer (score 1):

[https://www.amazon.com/Longitude-Genius-Greatest-Scientific-Problem/dp/080271529X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/080271529X)

I think you should read the book by Dava Sobell.  It will give you perspective and lead you to original source materials.  See:[https://www.amazon.com/Longitude-Genius-Greatest-Scientific-Problem/dp/080271529X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/080271529X)

Comment: Or you could watch the British television series from 2000, [Longitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude_(TV_series))